# question about python's csv.DictReader() when printing the first row

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file named "employee_birthday.txt":

```
name,department,birthday month
John Smith,Accounting,November
Erica Meyers,IT,March
```

The followinng script manage to print the content properly:

```
import csv

with open('employee_birthday.txt', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        print(f'\t{row["name"]} works in the {row["department"]} department, and was born in {row["birthday month"]}.')
        line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

The output is as follows:

```
Column names are name, department, birthday month
    John Smith works in the Accounting department, and was born in November.
    Erica Meyers works in the IT department, and was born in March.
Processed 3 lines.
```

Actually this is from an [online tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-csv/#reading-csv-files-into-a-dictionary-with-csv:%7E:text=Rather%20than%20deal,list%20containing%20them.) about csv. What puzzles me is the first iteration of the for loop. It seems the last two lines of the for loop got skipped magically and didn't print any thing during the first interation, even though there isn't a `else` or `continue` above the print (the 10th line). This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment as it was misleading. The `for` loop is iterating twice.  In the first iteration it prints out both the header/column-names and the first row of data for `John Smith`. On the second iteration it prints out the second row of data for `Erica Meyers`. The `for` loop ends and it prints out the `Processed 3 lines` message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add a simple `print('loop')` within your loop you'll see what's going on:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        print('loop')  # prints once per loop
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        print(f'\t{row["name"]} works in the {row["department"]} department, and was born in {row["birthday month"]}.')
        line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

The result is:

```
loop
Column names are name, department, birthday month
    John Smith works in the Accounting department, and was born in November.
loop
    Erica Meyers works in the IT department, and was born in March.
Processed 3 lines.
```

There's only 2 `loop`s printed. Because in a `DictReader` only the data values are looped through. The header row is already processed & headers are stored in the reader object.

When you do `print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')` the keys from the first data row dictionary are used to print that line since each row has the headers built-into it:

```
{'name': 'John Smith', 'department': 'Accounting', 'birthday month': 'November'}
```

You see the `Processed 3 lines` because in your first iteration, `line_count` is incremented twice.

Comment: I just realised that `.join()` can be used with dictionaries and `row` is a dictionary. That's the root of all the puzzling.